# Declare & Iterate collection<T>

Tags: c#, generics, boxing

I have the name & type of an object and the method name.
Ideally I would like to instantiate the object & call the method. All is well with that, but I am getting an error trying to process the results.

```
private void GetData(DropDownList ddl)
    {
        ObjectDataSource ods = (ObjectDataSource)ddl.DataSourceObject;
        System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = typeof(ExistingObject).Assembly;

        Type type = assembly.GetType(ods.SelectMethod);
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        IterateCollection(instance, ddl);
    }

    private static void IterateCollection<T>(T instance, DropDownList ddl) 
    {
        ObjectDataSource ods = (ObjectDataSource)ddl.DataSourceObject;
        Type type = instance.GetType();
        MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(ods.SelectMethod);

        LinkedList<T> col = (LinkedList<T>)methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { (T)instance });

        foreach (T o in col)
        {
            string textfield = Convert.ToString(GetPropValue(o, ddl.DataTextField));
            string valuefield = Convert.ToString(GetPropValue(o, ddl.DataValueField));
            ListItem li = new ListItem(textfield, valuefield);
            if ((bool?)GetPropValue(o, "Active") != true)
                li.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("background-color", "gray");
            ddl.Items.Add(li);
        }
    }
```

I am getting an error on the "Invoke" line saying 
``` System.InvalidCastException : 
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList``1[Business.Objects.MyType]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection ```1[System.Object]'.

I would like to be able to iterate through the collection. How can I do this?
How can I create a LinkedList or similar?

Thanks

Comment: how can I create `LinkedList<instance.GetType()>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the type `T` must always provide a method with the name stored in `ods.SelectMethod` and multiple properties. If `T` has to implement an interface containing this method, you can constrain `IterateCollection<T>` to that interface using:

```
   private static void IterateCollection<T>(T instance, DropDownList ddl)
       where T: IMyInterface
```

Assuming you cannot do that, use a `LinkedList<object>`. You are invoking the methods using reflection so generics will not give you any syntactic assistance.

Comment: I would like to achieve this without using the interface method. I still can't get past the InvalidCastException. Is it possible the way I am trying this? Many thanks

Comment: @user1652234 I escaped the `LinkedList<object>` which I forgot to do previous. Does using that work?

Comment: I got it working using: 
var collection = (IEnumerable)methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { instance });

            foreach (var o in collection)
            {

Thanks for your help, I greatly appreciate it